# Attempting to pass JSON body for deletion through AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I've currently got an endpoint that relies on a JSON body in order for deletion to happen. This is the following code:

```
if (toDeleteValue.length > 0) {
    var deleteRequest = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < toDeleteValue.length; i++) {
        var service = {};
        service.serviceId = $scope.siteServices[toDeleteService[i]].serviceId;
        toDeleteValue.push(service);
    }
    var deleteUrl = "api/class/" + $scope.targetEntity.serviceId+ "/student";

    await asyncDeleteUrl(deleteUrl, deleteRequest);

}

async function asyncDeleteUrl(deleteUrl, toBeDeleted) {    
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        $http.delete(deleteUrl, toBeDeleted)
        .then(function (response) {
            resolve(response);
        },
        function (errorResponse) {
            reject(errorResponse);
            $scope.statusDialog('Bad Modification Interrupted', errorResponse);
        });
   });
}
```

I keep getting an error saying the required rest body is missing but I'm not sure why that would be the case. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of the `$http.delete` method is a config object. Send data using the `data` property of that object:

```
function asyncDeleteUrl(deleteUrl, toBeDeleted) {
    var config = { data: toBeDeleted };    
    return $http.delete(deleteUrl, config)
    .catch(function (errorResponse) {
         $scope.statusDialog('Bad Modification Interrupted', errorResponse);
         throw errorResponse;
    });
}
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - delete](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#delete)